# Automate change in settings upon plugging mouse in

Tags: macos, automator, mouse, settings, automation

I am using a MacBook Air running Sierra.

I like to use different mouse settings with my touchpad, and my USB mouse. To facilitate this, every time I plug my mouse in, I have to go to `System Preferences` and change the mouse settings (reverse scroll direction and adjust sensitivity). Is there any way by which I can automate this change (maybe using automator) in settings to occur automatically every time I plug in the USB mouse?

Answer (score 1):

Under **macOS Sierra**, if you have only a normal **USB mouse**, not one that comes with it's own software and is multi-function with additional buttons, etc., then in **System Preferences** > **Mouse**, you have the following settings that can be changed:

- **Scroll direction: natural** *checkbox*
- **Tracking speed** *slider*
- **Scrolling Speed** *slider*
- **Double-Click speed** *slider*

And two additional settings under **Mouse** that will not be addressed, for two reasons, the **Primary mouse button:** *radio buttons*, if other then the *default* of **Left**, is in all likelihood already set and wouldn't necessarily change because one wants to change the **Scroll direction: natural** *checkbox*, and since the OP stated **USB mouse**, I'll assume is not using **Bluetooth** and can ignore the **Setup Bluetooth Mouse...** *button*.

This answer is going to use **AppleScript** to get the *before* and *after* settings for the *value* of the aforementioned listed *sliders* to be used in the **AppleScript** *code* that follows after this *code*.

Open **Script Editor** and create a new document, then add the following *code*:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.mouse"
    --delay 0.5 -- # If necessary, uncomment 'delay' command and set its value in seconds and or decimal fractions there of.
    tell application "System Events"
        log "Scrolling speed is set to: " & value in (get properties of slider 1 of front window of application process "System Preferences")
        log "Double-Click speed is set to: " & value in (get properties of slider 2 of front window of application process "System Preferences")
        log "Tracking speed is set to: " & value in (get properties of slider 3 of front window of application process "System Preferences")
    end tell
end tell
```

There will be two difference *states* of the **Scroll direction: natural** *checkbox* in **System Preferences** > **Mouse**, *checked* and *unchecked* and the change in *slider* settings between the two *states*.

The *code* above will be run once to get the current *value* settings of the *sliders*. Then make the setting changes that you want to the *sliders* for the opposite *state* of what it was when you gathered the *values* of the first settings for the first *state*. Then run the *code* again to get the differential settings.

You will then plug in the *values*, gathered above, in the *code* below. You can *comment* out or remove any *slider* that's not going to be changed by the *code* below.

The *comments* in the *code* below should be adequate, however, don't hesitate to ask it you need anything explained.

I saved the following **AppleScript** *code* in **Script Editor** as an application named **Toggle Mouse Settings** in the **Applications** folder.

When run, it toggles the *state* of the **Scroll direction: natural** *checkbox* between *checked* and *unchecked* along with the *slider* settings under each *state*.

**AppleScript** *code* for the **Toggle Mouse Settings** app:

```
on run
    try
        tell application "System Preferences"
            set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.mouse"
            -- delay 0.5    -- # If necessary, uncomment 'delay' command and set its value in seconds and or decimal fractions there of.
            tell application "System Events"
                set isChecked to get value of checkbox 1 of front window of application process "System Preferences" as boolean
                if isChecked then
                    --  # The 'Scroll direction: Natural' checkbox is checked, uncheck it.
                    set cbValue to value of (click checkbox 1 of front window of application process "System Preferences") as boolean
                    --  # Scrolling Speed - Valid Values: 0.0 to 8.0
                    set value of slider 1 of front window of application process "System Preferences" to 6.0
                    --  # Double-Click Speed - Valid Values: 0.0 to 10.0
                    set value of slider 2 of front window of application process "System Preferences" to 8.0
                    --  # Tracking Speed - Valid Values: 0.0 to 9.0
                    set value of slider 3 of front window of application process "System Preferences" to 6.0
                else
                    --  # The 'Scroll direction: Natural' checkbox is not checked, check it.
                    set cbValue to value of (click checkbox 1 of front window of application process "System Preferences") as boolean
                    --  # Scrolling Speed - Valid Values: 0.0 to 8.0
                    set value of slider 1 of front window of application process "System Preferences" to 4.5
                    --  # Double-Click Speed - Valid Values: 0.0 to 10.0
                    set value of slider 2 of front window of application process "System Preferences" to 8.0
                    --  # Tracking Speed - Valid Values: 0.0 to 9.0
                    set value of slider 3 of front window of application process "System Preferences" to 4.0
                end if
            end tell
            tell me
                if cbValue then
                    display notification "Natural scrolling is now active." with title (name of me)
                else
                    display notification "Natural scrolling is no longer active." with title (name of me)
                end if
            end tell
            quit
        end tell
    on error eStr number eNum
        activate
        display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "Toggle Mouse Settings" with icon caution
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
        return
    end try
end run
```

**Note:** Before running the **Toggle Mouse Settings** app, you'll need to add it to: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**

---

There is an app called [EventScripts](https://itunes.apple.com/app/eventscripts/id525319418?mt=12) that could be used to trigger when a USB device is plugged in and or removed. I have not used it before, just aware it exists.

There is also an app called [Scroll Reverser](http://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/). I have not used it before, just aware it exists.